# Page won't center

Tags: html, css, centering

I have tried wrapping my page and setting margin to 0 auto and width to 960px, but nothing works.

```css
body {
  background-image: url('http://wallpapercave.com/wp/adsKXLw.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: scroll;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}

#everything {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
}

#huge {
  width: 900px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255, 103, 48, 0.5);
  left: 75px;
  top: 0%;
}

.navbar div, .navbar div p {
  position: fixed;
}

#navbar-background {
  width: 820px;
  height: 110px;
  border-radius: 70px;
  top: 11px;
  left: 115px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255, .2);
  z-index: 1
}

#home-div {
  background-color: rgb(249, 162, 100);
  width: 210px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 135px;
  top: 30px;
  z-index: 2;
  border-top: 1px white solid;
  border-left: 1px solid white
}

#home-div-button {
  background-color: rgb(200, 131, 78);
  width: 215px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 40px;
  left: 140px;
  position: fixed;
}

#home-text {
  font-family: Comfortaa;
  text-align: center;
  top: 10px;
  left: 145px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}



#clan-div {
  width: 90px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 2px white solid;
  left: 505px;
  top: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}

#clan-text {
  left: 512px;
  top: 35px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Comfortaa;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#clan-div-2 {
  width: 90px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 2px white solid;
  left: 597px;
  top: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

#clan-text-2 {
  left: 610px;
  top: 35px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Comfortaa;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#games-div {
  width: 90px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 2px white solid;
  left: 712px;
  top: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#games-text {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Comfortaa;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  top: 35px;
  left: 723px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" text="text/css">
    <link href="script-1.js" type="text/javascript"> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="everything">
      <div id="huge"></div>
      <div class="navbar">

        <div id="navbar-background"></div>

        <div id="home-div">
          <p id="home-text"></p>
        </div>

        <div id="home-div-button"></div>

        <div id="clan-div">
          <p id="clan-text"></p>
        </div>

        <div id="clan-div-2">
          <p id="clan-text-2"></p>
        </div>

        <div id="games-div">
          <p id="games-text"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Expand the snippet and you'll see how it is sticking to the left. If I put the position to relative, then the navigation bar won't stay fixed at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend reading in to the exact way the different positioning types works, and how they effect there children. I have implemented what I assume is your desired behavior in the snippet below, main changes are giving `#everything` minimum height and using containers as backgrounds not separate divs. Make sure you compare this to your code, if you have any questions don't hesitate to drop a comment.

```css
body {
  background-image: url('http://wallpapercave.com/wp/adsKXLw.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  overflow: scroll;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}

#everything {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgba(255, 103, 48, 0.5);
}

#huge {
  width: 900px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255, 103, 48, 0.5);
  left: 75px;
  top: 0%;
}

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 960px;
  height: 110px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255, .2);
  border-radius: 70px;
}

#home-div {
  background-color: rgb(249, 162, 100);
  width: 210px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 135px;
  top: 22px;
  z-index: 2;
  border-top: 1px white solid;
  border-left: 1px solid white
}

#home-div-button {
  background-color: rgb(200, 131, 78);
  width: 215px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 32px;
  left: 140px;
  position: absolute;
}

#home-text {
  font-family: Comfortaa;
  text-align: center;
  top: 10px;
  left: 145px;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}



#clan-div {
  width: 90px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 2px white solid;
  left: 505px;
  top: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
}

#clan-text {
  left: 512px;
  top: 35px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Comfortaa;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#clan-div-2 {
  width: 90px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 2px white solid;
  left: 597px;
  top: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

#clan-text-2 {
  left: 610px;
  top: 35px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Comfortaa;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

#games-div {
  width: 90px;
  height: 45px;
  border: 2px white solid;
  left: 712px;
  top: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#games-text {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Comfortaa;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  top: 35px;
  left: 723px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" text="text/css">
    <link href="script-1.js" type="text/javascript"> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="everything">
      <div class="navbar">
        <div id="home-div">
          <p id="home-text"></p>
        </div>

        <div id="home-div-button"></div>

        <div id="clan-div">
          <p id="clan-text"></p>
        </div>

        <div id="clan-div-2">
          <p id="clan-text-2"></p>
        </div>

        <div id="games-div">
          <p id="games-text"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't really understand what you did and why it helped. Is there a specific attribute that you changed?

Comment: Also, I don't know how to make the nav bar not take up the entire length of the #huge and be centered in it. I tried just making the .nav have a shorter width and then using left: 100px, but that made it stop scaling properly when I zoomed in or out with my browser.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set both a `width` *and* a `position` [property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) for your *outer* wrapping element to achieve center; along with your `margin: 0 auto;`

*ie.*

```
.pagewrap { 
   width: 960px;
   position: relative;
   margin: 0 auto;
   height: auto;
}
```

Hope this helps!